# lambda return type restriction for C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, return, return-type

So i am working on a C++11 project and i have class structure something like this

header file

```
class AgentClassInterface {
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};
class AgentClass : public AgentClassInterface {
public:
    void doSomething() {};
    AgentClass() = default;
    virtual ~AgentClass() = default;
    static std::shared_ptr<AgentClass> create();
};

using SetUpFunctionTest =
    std::function<std::pair<bool, std::shared_ptr<AgentClassInterface>>(int)>;

class ManagerTest{
    ManagerTest(const SetUpFunctionTest& setupFunction);
private:
    SetUpFunctionTest m_setUpFunction;
};
```

the cpp file

```
ManagerTest::ManagerTest(const SetUpFunctionTest& setupFunction)
        :  m_setUpFunction(setupFunction) {
}

std::shared_ptr<AgentClass> AgentClass::create(){
    auto agentClass = std::shared_ptr<AgentClass>(new AgentClass());
    return agentClass;
}
```

now in my application.cpp i have code like this

```
auto setUpFunc = [&](int i) {
    std::shared_ptr<AgentClass> agentInstance = AgentClass::create();

    if(!agentInstance){
        return std::make_pair(false, nullptr);
    }

    return std::make_pair(true,agentInstance);
};
```

this is returning an error like

```
/Users/sharmajs/AlexaWorkspace/CA_Manager_POC/projects/avs-cpp-sdk/ApplicationUtilities/DefaultClient/src/DefaultClient.cpp:754:5: error: return type 'pair<[...], typename __unwrap_ref_decay<shared_ptr<AgentClass> &>::type>' must match previous return type 'pair<[...], typename __unwrap_ref_decay<std::nullptr_t>::type>' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
return std::make_pair(true,agentInstance);
^
```

Reading online it seems like lambda can only have one return statement if i understand correctly and the return type should match so i could technically fix the compilation error by modifying my code like this

```
    auto setUpFunc = [&](int i) {
    std::shared_ptr<AgentClass> agentInstance = AgentClass::create();

    if(!agentInstance){
        return std::make_pair(false, std::shared_ptr<AgentClass>(nullptr));
    }

    return std::make_pair(true,agentInstance);
};
```

but that is not desired as now i have to specify `AgentClass` i want to somehow specify the return type `AgentClassInterface` in the `SetUpFunctionTest`  so that the application code can even have a return statement like this `return std::make_pair(false, nullptr);` if needed
Please note that i have have other classes also that inherit from `AgentClassInterface` for full context that the application can provide that other `ManagerTest` class can use for setup.

Can someone please advise or provide feedback on how i can achieve my desired invocation or any other suggestion/alternatives that could make application code easier to invoke.

Comment: Please specify trailing return type for your lambda: auto setUpFunc = [&](int i) -> std::pair<bool, std::shared_ptr<AgentClassInterface >> { ... }

Also your AgentClassInterface class shall define virtual destructor.

Comment: thanks @tomaszmi so i need to provide trailing return type than what i do not understand is the significance of having return type in declaration of SetUpFunctionTest

Comment: Compiler deduces the return type for you. But it can't deduce what you mean if one `return` tries to return `std::pair<bool, std::shared_ptr<AgentClass>>` and the other `return` tries to return `std::pair<bool, std::nullptr_t>`. You need to tell it what do you actually mean and which one should be converted to which.

Comment: I'm not sure about the lambda, but why not just check if the shared pointer is valid? Whenever I see a `pair<bool, ...>` I immediate think "this should be `std::optional`."

Comment: In this case, a `shared_ptr` can hold a `nullptr`, which you can check for. `SetUpFunctionTest()` should just return a `shared_ptr` which will either be `nullptr` or not. The `bool` is completely redundant and should be removed. `using SetUpFunctionTest = std::function<std::shared_ptr<AgentClassInterface>(int)>;` ... `auto setUpFunc = [&](int i) -> std::shared_ptr<AgentClassInterface> { return AgentClass::create(); };`

Comment: i have a pair to differentiate between the use case of when the callback does not create a instance and it should not be an error i.e <true, nullptr> implies callback choose not to create an instance vs <false,nullptr> something bad happened

Comment: @bourne If something bad happens, you should `throw` an exception instead. `return shared_ptr(<object>);` on success if an object is created, `return shared_ptr(nullptr);` on success if an object is not needed, and `throw <exception>;` if a failure occurs. Let the caller use `try..catch` if it wants to catch the exception. Otherwise, if you don't want the overhead of exceptions, then I agree with Aaron, use `std::optional<shared_ptr>` instead of `std::pair<bool, shared_ptr>`